# How to add columns depending on a table's value

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

So I have a students table, students_exams relation table and exams table.

```
---------
|Student|
--------
Id
Name
Surname

-------
|Exams|
-------
Id
Result

----------------
|Students_Exams|
----------------
student_id (FK)
exam_id (FK)
ExamNumber
```

So the problem is I have to show Student name+surname (with concat) and exams (max number can be 4) as columns and exam results. And if the student did not take the exam (so if there is no record on the table) it should return N/A. So the select query should return something like

```
Name-Surname     Exam1  Exam2  Exam3 Exam4
--------------------------------------------------------
Keanu Reeves      82     N/A    55    65
Andy War          N/A    N/A    68    N/A
```

and so forth. My problem is showing the exams as above with a select query. How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

With regards to GMB's answer

It gave the result below:

```
Name-Surname     Exam1  Exam2  Exam3 Exam4
--------------------------------------------------------
Keanu Reeves       82    N/A    N/A  N/A 
Keanu Reeves      N/A    N/A    N/A  N/A
Keanu Reeves      N/A    N/A    55   N/A
Keanu Reeves      N/A    N/A    N/A  65
```

Comment: What about students with no exams at all, should they be included in the result?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: @jarlh yes, no exams at all should be seen as N/A for all exams

Comment: @Strawberry I have to do it with sql

Comment: Switch to  `LEFT JOIN` to also include the students with no exams at all.

Comment: Well, when I join them, it returns no records. I believe its looking for students with all exams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pivot over a fixed list of examps, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    concat(s.name, '-', s.surname) name_surname,
    max(case when e.name = 'Exam1' then e.result end) exam1,
    max(case when e.name = 'Exam2' then e.result end) exam2,
    max(case when e.name = 'Exam3' then e.result end) exam3,
    max(case when e.name = 'Exam4' then e.result end) exam4
from student s
inner join student_exams se on se.student_id = s.id
inner join exams e on e.id = se.exam_id
group by s.id, s.name, s.surname
```

Notes:

- this assumes  that table `exams` has a column called `name` that stores the name of the exam
- you cannot put string `'N/A'` in a numeric column (otherwise, you would need to force the conversion of all exam notes to strings instead of numbers) - the above query will yield `null` for students that did not take a given exam, which seems to me like the relevant manner to indicate that this student did not take that exam

Comment: It does not return students with no attendancy

Comment: @DevelopmentPeasant: for this, you can turn both `inner join`s to `left join`s.

Comment: last question, it gave a strange result I'm editing the question. How can I merge them?